# How to find limit of a geometric sequence

Tags: limits

Let $S_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^5} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{(2n+1)}}$. What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}+...)$$
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^3}+...)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} \quad{........|x|<1}$$
$$r=\frac{1}{4} $$
so
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}})$$

Comment: How are we sure that $S_n$ converges? I think you should add the convergence proof to to make a complete answer.

Comment: @Stefan4024 $r<1$

Comment: I know that the proof is rather trivial, but whenver we say equate an infinite series to some number we should be certain that it converges. Therefore I mentioned that one should add the convergence proof too.